# EasyMock capture: use getValue() outside of an IAnswer

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, capture, easymock

Suppose I want to test a method `Foo.doSomething(String arg):String` using **EasyMock**. I know that I can use *EasyMock Capture* in order to capture the value set inside of the parameter and then get it at a later time. When writing my test, my goal is to capture the value when I mock out Foo's method and then get the value of the capture outside of my mocked method. I am trying something like this:

```
Capture<String> stringCapture = new Capture<String>();
EasyMock.expect(foo.doSomething(EasyMock.capture(stringCapture)).andAnswer(new IAnswer<String> {
    @Override
    public String answer() throws Throwable {
        ...
});
String retrievedValue = stringCapture.getValue();
```

However, I get a runtime error when I try to use `getValue()`:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Nothing captured yet
    at org.easymock.Capture.getValue(Capture.java:80)
    at com.example.Test.myTest(...)
    ....
```

I wish I could have a `String` variable within my test method but outside of the `IAsnwer` closure and set that variable's value inside of my `IAnswer.answer()` method. The problem is that the `String` variable must be marked as `final` in order to be accessible to the closure, which makes it unmodifiable and hence useless. Also, I do not wish to use a global just to solve this.

The only workaround I've thought of it to use my own class that has a String field, declare it as a `final` variable outside of `IAnswer`, set the captured value during `answer()` and finally set this value into a field within my test method. Perhaps there's a better way to do this because using another class to extract a captured value, or even a global variable, seems ugly to me.

Comment: you should retrieve captured value **after** you executed your main test sequence that leads to `foo.doSomething` call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getValue will only work after the actual (replayed) call to foo. Before that, nothing is capture.

To set a variable inside answer(), because of Java requesting variables used in an inner class to be final, I normally use an AtomicReference. It's a nice placeholder for such things. The AtomicReference is then final but its content isn't.

Comment: I am no longer working on the project that was using EasyMock, but I'll give your suggestion a try the next time I do. Thank you.